# Check if an input box exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation

I have to check if confirm_password input box exists in form.
If it exists, 
I need to do this:

```
validates :password,:confirmation=>true
```

else

set confirmation to false.

**Detail explanation for the problem:**

I'm using rails client_side_validation gem which converts models validation into javascript form validation.

There is a little problem with this as login and sign up belongs to same table both of them have one Model. Now when I'm adding this in model for validation:

```
validates :password,:confirmation=>true
```

It will not let me to login as validation will become false as there is no confirm_password input box  on login.It will only work on signup.

Comment: Why wouldn't you know if the confirm_password box exists?  Isn't your app creating the view?  Perhaps posting some existing code will shed some light here...

Comment: Actually I have two forms one login and one signup ... I need to differentiate between them in the model as they are validated through the same model.

Comment: Do they post to the same controller action?  If so, why?  If not, then have the controller set the model accordingly in the action.

Comment: The model is same both go to the same model.

Comment: Please post controller code for both login and signup actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a model User add `@user.is_signup = true` to the signup action in users_controller. In your User model add `attribute_accessor :is_signup` and `validates :confirm_password, :confirmation => true, :if => :is_signup`.

Answer (score 1):

In your signup form you could have a hidden field that gets passed in the form. If the attribute is present and returns `true` then you validate the presence of the password confirmation.

Signup form, somewhere inside the form tags:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :is_signup, true %>
```

Model:

```
attribute_accessor :confirm_password
attribute_accessor :is_signup

validates :confirm_password, :presence => true, :if => :validate_confirm_password?

def validate_confirm_password?
  is_signup
end
```

Comment: Now i'm getting this error undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass  on the signupform. This is what i have done on my model   attribute_accessor :is_signup  validates :password, :confirmation=> true, :if => :validate_confirm_password?    def validate_confirm_password?
       is_signup
  end

Comment: Right, sorry, my first answer kind of sucked, in retrospect. It's simpler than that. Try the top answer.